# jQuery prevent default issues in firefox and IE

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, internet-explorer-7

trying to debug this page http://goo.gl/Z7xaA

seems to work fine in Google Chrome, but both firefox and internet explorer throw errors.

IE & FF Both don't like the prevent default action I've put on all 'a' elements to prevent it skipping to the top of the page when clicked.

As I said, works fine and no errors in chrome, various errors and faults in IE and Firefox.

IE doesn't calculate the rate x price totals either.. If anyone can help me debug the errors so I can improve me JS skills that would be great.

Cheers

Comment: I looked at the page source and posted an answer. But please in the future **always post code**. It makes it so much easier, and you will get a lot more people looking at it.

Comment: Also, please post your other question as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

You are not accessing the event correctly. In jQuery, all callbacks pass a normalized event as their first parameter. Change your anchor click handler to this:

```
$("a").click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: hmmm both answers seem to give the same result - working in firefox but no IE.

Comment: Message: Unexpected call to method or property access.
Line: 103
Char: 460
Code: 0
URI: http://www.microhire.com/js/jquery.min.js

Comment: ^ that's the only "error" according IE now... not sure what to do there.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
if (event.preventDefault) { event.preventDefault(); } else { event.returnValue = false; }
});
```

You need to define event first :)